# Erro de parse no Less, diz que minha classe/mixin não está definida

Tags: css, less

Estou usando ruby 1.9.2 e rails 3 e gem less 2.6.0. Já importei o `mixins` e o `variables` e mesmo assim o erro persiste.

> Less::ParseError: #gradient > .vertical is undefined

Trecho do arquivo slider.less:

```
.slider-track {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    #gradient > .vertical(#f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
    .box-shadow(inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1));
    .border-radius(@baseBorderRadius);
```

Comment: Poderia ser um erro de sintaxe no seu LESS? Pode postar o trecho do arquivo onde aparece essa regra?

Comment: editei a pergunta, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Qual é a intenção com `#gradient > .vertical(#f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);`? Qual é o CSS que você espera gerar?

Comment: pra ser sincero eu não tenho certeza, por isso eu não consigo resolver sozinho, é um código que já veio pronto no Silder para Bootstrap (bootstrap.slider).

Comment: O que você tem aí é um [mixin paramétrico](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature). Precisa ter uma definição desse `.vertical(@cor1; @cor2)` em algum lugar.

Comment: valeu cara, me ajudou :)

Comment: @bfavaretto não compensa colocar como resposta? :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Feito. Espero que isso salve a pergunta do fechamento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse `.vertical(#f5f5f5, #f9f9f9)` é o que o Less chama de [mixin pramétrico](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature), que é como uma função que recebe parâmetros. Ele precisa ser declarado em algum lugar. Imagino que você esteja querendo algo assim:

```
.vertical(@cor1, @cor2) {

  /* Fallback (could use .jpg/.png alternatively) */
  background-color: @cor1;

  /* SVG fallback for IE 9 (could be data URI, or could use filter) */
  background-image: url(fallback-gradient.svg); 

  /* Safari 4, Chrome 1-9, iOS 3.2-4.3, Android 2.1-3.0 */
  background-image:
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@cor1), to(@cor2));

  /* Safari 5.1, iOS 5.0-6.1, Chrome 10-25, Android 4.0-4.3 */
  background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @cor1, @cor2);

  /* Firefox 3.6 - 15 */
  background-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(top, @cor1, @cor2);

  /* Opera 11.1 - 12 */
  background-image:
    -o-linear-gradient(top, @cor1, @cor2);

  /* Opera 15+, Chrome 25+, IE 10+, Firefox 16+, Safari 6.1+, iOS 7+, Android 4.4+ */
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, @cor1, @cor2);

}
```

<sup>Compatibilidade com múltiplos browsers baseada nas dicas do [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)</sup>